# Bitwise or (|) in function argument

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I was wondering how to do this:

```
func(param1|param2|param3)
```

and then extract those values in the function, I have seen this in multiple functions, or is it better to do this:

```
func(param1, ...)
```

?

I am trying to do this in C++, and I was thinking of having the parameters to the function as values in a enum.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Param1, param2, param3 are usually defined as a numbers with different bits turned on.
`|` is an operator of bitwise alternative, that means it works on separate bits.

In example:

```
const int param1 = 0x01;
const int param2 = 0x02;
const int param3 = 0x04;
```

When you pass an argument to function you make a bitwise alternative of earlier defined params.
In function, you don't make a decomposition, but check if a specified bit is set on, using bitwise conjunction:

```
void func(int arg){
  if(arg & param1)
    // do something
  if(arg & param2)
    // do something else
    // ...
}

func(param1 | param3); 
// "do something" will be done,
// but "do something else" not.
```

Comment: You can also define numbers like `int param1and2 = 0x03;` which act like `param1 | param2`;

Comment: It should be perhaps noted that restoring the `|` arguments back is possible only for specific argument patterns, like those presented in the answer. Otherwise this would be not possible: `3 | 4` is the same as `1 | 6`.

Comment: Thanks guys!

This is what I ended up doing as paxdiablo suggested

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you have the values as independent bits (powers of two) like:

```
#define IS_ON    0x01
#define IS_LARGE 0x02
#define IS_RED   0x04
```

(or the equivalent `enums` or `const int` values, depending on how you want to do them - I've used `#define` simply because it's what I'm used to), you can *pass* them as:

```
funcname (IS_ON | IS_RED);   // passes in 0x05
```

Then you *extract* them with something like:

```
void funcname (int bitmask) {
    if ((bitmask & IS_ON) == IS_ON) { // 0x05 & 0x01 -> 0x01
        // IS_ON bit is set.
    }
    :
}
```

For single-bit specifiers, you can get away with the `if (bitmask & IS_ON)` form but you need the full check if your specifiers may be multi-bit values (like a three-bit volume level of 0 through 7, for example).

Comment: What would be the bitwise operator combination for is_not_on_and_is_not_red? Would it be `funcname (~IS_ON | ~IS_RED);`?

Comment: clear explanation , but you should mention that the bits should be powers of 2 . Right ?

Comment: Instead of constants `0x01` you could use `1<<0`, `1<<2`, `1<<3` etc. I find those more readable.

Comment: @el.pescado, young padawan, when my age you get to, powers of two you will know instantly :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an useful example to how create "MessageBox" function with arbitrary button types :

```
enum Button
{
    OK =      0x0001,
    CANCEL =  0x0010,
    YES =     0x0100,
    NO =      0x1000
};

void messagebox(char *text, int button)
{
    char msg[256];
    strcpy(msg, text);

    if ((button & Button::OK) == Button::OK)
        strcat(msg, " [OK]");
    if ((button & Button::CANCEL) == Button::CANCEL)
        strcat(msg, " [Cancel]");
    if ((button & Button::YES) == Button::YES)
        strcat(msg, " [Yes]");
    if ((button & Button::NO) == Button::NO)
        strcat(msg, " [No]");

    cout << msg << endl;
}

int main()
{
    messagebox("salam", Button::OK | Button::CANCEL);
    return 0;
}
```